# What is the best way to extract text between tracking params using regex?

Tags: regex

I have some data that I need help cleaning up.  For some reason, tracking params are being stored within the database so what is the best way to extract the search query minus the tracking params using regex?  I need to extract the following search queries:

- things to do
- las vegas
- airport parking

from the following data:

- {"query":"things to do","prefilteredchannel":"gpse
- {"query":"las vegas","prefilteredchannel":"gpsea
- {"query":"airport parking

I've tried a few things but I can only match the things I don't care about and I don't know how to just extract the search query.   I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Any ideas on how to make this work with the Platfora regex_replace:

http://documentation.platfora.com/webdocs/index.html#reference/expression_language/function_regex_replace.html

Answer (score 0):

use this regex . its quite simple

```
{"query":"([^"]*)(?:"|$)
```

See demo here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yK3bI2/1)

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work with the Platfora regex_replace:

http://documentation.platfora.com/webdocs/index.html#reference/expression_language/function_regex_replace.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
\{"query":"([^"]*|$)
```

It will match the query value until `"` is encountered or end of string (whichever comes first).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE4zA5/1)

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work with the Platfora regex_replace:

http://documentation.platfora.com/webdocs/index.html#reference/expression_language/function_regex_replace.html

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work with the Platfora regex_replace:

http://documentation.platfora.com/webdocs/index.html#reference/expression_language/function_regex_replace.html